# forwarded argument is not moved. why?

Tags: c++11, perfect-forwarding

in the following code the first call to logAndProcess picks the process function with const reference, the second one picks the process function with r-value reference.
My question: shouldn't have the r-value function moved the argument string? Apparently it didn't. Why?

code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

void process(std::string && rvalue)
{
    std::string local = rvalue; // shouldn't rvalue have moved to local?

    printf("process &&rvalue. local: %s\n",local.c_str());
}


void process(const std::string & rvalue)
{
    printf("process const &rvalue\n");
}


template<class T>
void logAndProcess(T &&arg)
{
    printf("\nbefore process\n");
    process( std::forward<T>(arg) ); // picks the right overload of process one, depending on argument type.
    printf("after process\n");
}

main()
{
    //logAndProcess(std::string("aaa")); // called with rvalue - calls process(string &&)

    std::string tmp("tmp");
    logAndProcess(tmp); // calls process(const string &)

    printf("tmp not moved: %s\n", tmp.c_str());


    logAndProcess(std::move(tmp)); // calls process(string &&)

    printf("tmp moved?: %s\n not!", tmp.c_str());


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
before process
process const &rvalue
after process
tmp not moved: tmp

before process
process &&rvalue. local: tmp
after process
tmp moved?: tmp
```

I understand the rule that 'if it has a name then its a n lvalue'; however in the following example the variable with an lvalue is moved. What is different in the case of the function with forwarding?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  std::string src("aaa");

  std::string movedStr = std::move (src);

  printf("movedStr: %s src: %s\n", movedStr.c_str(), src.c_str());

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

`movedStr: aaa src:`

Comment: in short, even though `process(string&&)` only accepts rvalue references, `rvalue` is an *lvalue* within the function

Comment: I edited he question: provided example when local variable is moved (variable with value - lvalue shouldn't have been moved). What is different?

Comment: because `std::move` accepts an lvalue and returns an rvalue reference to that lvalue so that it can be moved

Comment: ok, that is exactly what the second call was doing: logAndProcess(std::move(tmp)); And forwarding within the function picked the r-value version, as the calling function received an r-value argument; however no move happened.

Comment: Your initial code would behave as you expect if you changed `std::string local = rvalue;` to `std::string local = std::move(rvalue);` The point is, just because you `std::move`-ed to call a function doesn't remove the need to `std::move` from the argument if you actually want to move from it.

Comment: again, `rvalue` is _not_ an rvalue reference like the function signature will have you believe, it is an lvalue. you need to `move` it *again* so that `local` uses the move constructor

Comment: thanks @ShadowRanger ! This did change it !!! Now I am still confused as std::move is supposed to cast to an r-value; however the function is already receiving an r-value argument. Why do we need the std::move call within he process function?

Comment: @MichaelMoser: Because the `&&` in the prototype says it *receives* an r-value reference (for templates, a universal forwarding reference), but as others have already told you, a named r-value reference *is an l-value* and must be explicitly converted back to an r-value reference with `std::move` to use it as such.